# click button does something, then click same button undo it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a button create a line through a list but if you click it again it'll undo the line-through. I've tried a `.toggle()` but it did not work:

original code:

```
$("div").on("click", ".doneButt", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents("li").css("text-decoration", "line-through");   
});
```

.toggle attempt:

```
$(".doneButt").toggle(function() {
    $(this).parents("li").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
}, function() {
    $(this).parents("li").css("text-decoration", "none");
});
```

Comment: you can add or remove class with that style. use `.toggleClass()`

Comment: The [`.toggle()` event method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was *removed* in jQuery v1.9. Use a `.click()` handler instead, and a class with `.toggleClass()` or an `if/else` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$(".doneButt").click(function() {
  $(this).parents("li").toggleClass('withline');
});
```

```css
.withline {
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>asdasdasda
    <input type='button' class='doneButt' value='Click' />
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. Using `.toggleClass()`

Comment: this is a perfect answer

Comment: @OrangePineapple glad to help mate

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".doneButt" ).on("click",function() {
        var style = $(this).attr("style")+"";
        if(style=="undefined")
            $(this).parents("li").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
        else
            $(this).parents("li").removeAttr("style");
        });
```

Comment: Removing the `style` could have unwanted effects.

Comment: doesnt matter you are adding and removing style i mean undo means removing the style attribute

Comment: What if the element has other style properties unrelated to `text-decoration`? This code will remove those properties too.

Comment: if you add them in css it does not remove but if you add inline css yes it removes and my answer not working